# What did Clu's army chant just before his speech to them?

Tags: tron-legacy

Clu's army chanted something just prior to his speech to them, but I can't tell what they are saying. The chant is at the beginning of this video:

As a guess, it sounds like they're saying

> Ar-my...Clu

but that doesn't entirely make sense.

I've been unable to find a script of the movie, except for an [early draft](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/TRON-Legacy.html) that doesn't have much in common with the released movie.

**What is Clu's army chanting? Is it intelligible or just a vocalization?**

I'm not looking for guesses -- I'm looking for an answer from an up to date script, interview with the filmmakers, etc.

Comment: It sounds like "Clu Army".

Comment: @Richard That would make more sense, but they start with the part that sounds like "army".

Comment: No help in the [official graphic novelisation](https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/TRON:_Legacy_Graphic_Novel). The army is just standing there - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY2Nq.jpg